# Multimaster replication with multiple slaves with MariaDB/Mysql

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, mariadb

Is it possible to receive the following configuration with Maria DB/MySQL:
Two master nodes with synchronous replication (actually need one, second need for failover and could be asynchronous ),
N slaves nodes with asynchronous replication,
We want to use Amazon EC2 with autoscale. 
What are the pitfalls?
Which better for this task: Mysql or MariaDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "synchronous Multi-Master replication" in standard replication.

Sounds like you would benefit from MariaDB with Galera.  With that, you not only get synchronous replication, but also *automatic* recovery from server failure.